# Smart Lock SDK is not retrieving credential sets correctly for NexusPlayer( Android TV )

Tags: android, google-api, google-play-services, google-smartlockpasswords

Im currently setting up smart lock for our tv app in nexus player.

The problem is that even though i already saved few credential sets for my google account through our mobile app( which implemented the smart lock sdk long ago ), i cant retrieve all of them in our tv app.
[image]

**in our Tv app , i can only retrieve one of those credentials.**

And whats even stranger is that if i try to save my one of my credentials through my tv app, **which is already existing in the cloud ( the account begins with 6249**) , it will be saved and you can see duplicated credentials . And after that i can retrieve this credentials from smart lock in the tv app.

[image]
[image]

Noted that the app's domain is the same for both tv app and our mobile app.

Comment: Sounds like the apps have the same package, but are they signed with the same keystore? (e.g. if you have save credentials from the production Android app, but you use a TV app build with debug or development keys, the two will not be associated automatically for security). Let me know, otherwise, we can take a closer look to investigate!

Comment: oh, yeah you are right, im using different keystores! let me try the same keystore and let u know if it works, thanks Steven ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve saved credentials through [`CredentialsApi.request()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/credentials/CredentialsApi) method.

```
Auth.CredentialsApi.request(mCredentialsClient, mCredentialRequest).setResultCallback(
new ResultCallback<CredentialRequestResult>() {
@Override
public void onResult(CredentialRequestResult credentialRequestResult) {
if (credentialRequestResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
// See "Handle successful credential requests"
onCredentialRetrieved(credentialRequestResult.getCredential());
} else {
// See "Handle unsuccessful and incomplete credential requests"
resolveResult(credentialRequestResult.getStatus());
}
}
});
```

**Handle multiple saved credentials:**

When user input is required to select a credential, the [`getStatusCode()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) method returns [`RESOLUTION_REQUIRED`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes). In this case, call the status object's [`startResolutionForResult()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult) method to prompt the user to choose an account. Then, retrieve the user's chosen credentials from the activity's onActivityResult() method by passing `Credential.EXTRA_KEY` to the [`getParcelableExtra()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String)) method.

Here's a documentation how to Store credentials: https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/store-credentials#store_credentials